# grails plugin DSL specify zip file

Tags: grails, plugins

When using the grails plugin dsl in BuildConfig.groovy, such as

```
plugins {
    build "org.grails.plugins:db-util:0.4"
}
```

Is there a way to specify to use a plugin from a zip file like you can do with `grails install-plugin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly, but of you put the zip file in a directory and name it without the `grails-` prefix, then declare that directory as a `flatDir` repository then Grails will be able to resolve the plugin from there.

```
repositories {
  flatDir name:'localPlugins', dirs:'../local-plugins'
}
// copy plugin zip to ../local-plugins/my-plugin-1.2.zip
plugins {
  compile ':my-plugin:1.2'
}
```

Or if it's a locally built plugin you could install it into your local maven cache using `grails maven-install` and just use `mavenLocal()` instead of the `flatDir`.